# Subcategories aren't populating using fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch, html-select, optgroup

I'm trying to create `<optgroup>`s that have subcategories pulled from an API. Currently, only the `<optgroup>`s are populating, but not the subcategories.

```
let select = document.querySelector("#category");
const categoriesURL = "INSERT_URL"
  
let str = "";

fetch(categoriesURL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(category => {
      let categoryTitle = category.title;
      str += `<optgroup label=${categoryTitle}></optgroup>`
      category.subcategories.forEach(sub => {
        let subcategories_id = sub.subcategories_id;
        let subcategoriesURL = `INSERT_URL/${subcategories_id}`;
        fetch(subcategoriesURL)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(subData => {
          str += `<option value=${sub.subcategories_id}>` + subData.title + "</option>";
        })
      })
  })
  select.innerHTML = "<option disabled selected>Select a category</option>" + str;
});
```

Comment: You should not keep your dev url in your question, anyone can do whatever they want right now. I checked and no authentication is required to add or remove stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining your `optgroup` in the string, you immediately open and close the optgroup, effectively putting every option after the optgroup.

```
str += `<optgroup label=${categoryTitle}></optgroup>`
```

Leave the `optgroup` open in the aforementioned string.

However, the hard part is closing the string *after* all the `fetch` requests on the subcategories are complete. We can accomplish this with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Loop over all the subcategories with `map` and return `Promise` that `fetch` returns in the loop. When all the `fetch` requests are done the code will continue to the `then` block that follows the `Promise.all` function. In that block you will have the ids and titles of *all* your subcategories collected in an array. Loop over array to append to your string.

After the loop, close the `optgroup` element.

```
fetch(categoriesURL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(category => {
      let categoryTitle = category.title;
      str += `<optgroup label=${categoryTitle}>`;

      Promise.all(category.subcategories.map(sub => {
        let subcategories_id = sub.subcategories_id;
        let subcategoriesURL = `INSERT_URL/${subcategories_id}`;

        return fetch(subcategoriesURL)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(({ title }) => ({
            title,
            id: subcategories_id
          }))
      })).then(subData => {
        subData.forEach(({ id, title }) => {
          str += `<option value=${id}>${title}</option>`;
        })
        
        str += '</optgroup>';
      });
    })

    select.innerHTML = "<option disabled selected>Select a category</option>" + str;
  });
```

Though, overall this a very expensive script as it will create a lot of requests. If you have any say over the backend, then I'd advice that you send the all the data back in a single request and create your list based on that result.